# Error while using 'patch' function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, patch

I am trying to plot quadrilateral patches of a surface mesh of a 3d object.. I have `x,y,z` which are `4Xn` where 4 is for each vertex of the quadrilateral and n is the number of quadrilaterals,`c` which is a 3Xn RGB matrix. when use `patch( x, y, z,c);`
I get the error

```
`Error using patch`
`Size of C must match sizes of X Y [Z]`
```

But this works for `x,y,z` which are `3Xn` for triangular patches and `c` a 3Xn RGB vector. Please correct where i am going wrong.

Comment: Please post the code you are using (or as minimal example as you can create which still returns the error).

Comment: Hi here is the link to the variables [Gdrive] <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bWIsPfRR1dR2VxV2JFTGV0d00/view?usp=sharing> the function is 'patch( vertQuad.x, vertQuad.y, vertQuad.z,cQuad);'

Comment: I don't think you included the cQuad data

Comment: sorry <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bWIsPfRR1dSDhneGttbGx2UlU/view?usp=sharing> here is the corrected link.

Comment: Cheers,
Does this produce the result you want?

patch( vertQuad.x, vertQuad.y, vertQuad.z,'FaceColor','flat','FaceVertexCData',cQuad');

Comment: unfortunately no.. I dont know why for some reason the z coordinate for all points is zero...i have added the data pertaining to triangular patches in this file for reference, may be it helps..<http://bit.ly/1OdSPzT>

Comment: how odd, works for me..

Comment: Are you sure you're defining your vertices correctly? Can you get the patches you want without defining the colours? From a colour perspective the reason you were getting the error is that CData expects a 3d matrix, FaceVertexCData expects a 3coloumed matrix where columns 1,2,3 are R,G,B respectively http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#prop_FaceVertexCData

Comment: @Tom thanks a lot for your help and the link..now i know what mistake i was making..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving a single RGB value for each `patch`, you'd need to give `patch` a value for each vertex you are drawing (due to the format of your data).

So with your data and this line:

```
cQuad=permute(repmat(cQuad,[1 1 4]),[3 2 1]);

patch(vertQuad.x,vertQuad.y,vertQuad.z,cQuad)
```

Works fine. What I do is repeat the colours 4 times using `repmat` and then order the dimensions in the format `patch` likes using `permute`

Comment: Thanks Ander...is this explicitly mentioned in any manual or is it just understood based on function syntax.

Comment: @manoj Patch can be a bit tricky sometimes, as depending on what input format you give and what colour format you use (indexed, RGB,...) it is prepared to do things differently. However sometimes it is a bit confusing! I think the Matlab help should be a bit more specific ! In this case, when I transposed the matrix the error hanged and said `C should be [MxN] or [MxNx3]` so I guessed that it needed to be for each vertex.

Comment: thanks i get it now.. and the error i got left me clueless..if you dont mind can you remove the pic from the answer..